# Android DrawerLayout fails when using TOP and BOTTOM gravities

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm just playing around with the new [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) recently included in support library. I've implemented just a simple to example with multiple drawers, while I was using START and END as gravities it all worked like a charm, but when trying to add a drawer with TOP or BOTTOM gravities it crashes.

Is it possible to use it for sliding drawers from top and/or bottom?

Below is the full code for my activity and the xml layout in a working state; If I try to change this:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
                  android:layout_width="240dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_gravity="end"
                  android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                  android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                  android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                  android:background="#007799"/>
```

into this (notice changes in layout_width, layout_height and layout_gravity):

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="300dp"
                  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                  android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                  android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                  android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                  android:background="#007799"/>
```

and the line:

```
this.drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

info this one:

```
this.drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

is when I get the following error:

```
05-16 05:22:33.981    1503-1503/es.luixal.test                 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.luixal.test/es.luixal.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.RelativeLayout{42664c80 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0} is not a sliding drawer
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.RelativeLayout{42664c80 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0} is not a sliding drawer
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:970)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1003)
        at es.luixal.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        ... 11 more
```

Any clues of why can't I use this other gravities?

Thanks!

**MainActivity.java**

```
package es.luixal.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // filling list items:
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{
            "MenuItem 1",
            "MenuItem 2",
            "MenuItem 3"
    });
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //
    this.drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    this.drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:text="Hi!"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
              android:layout_width="240dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="start"
              android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
              android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
              android:dividerHeight="0dp"
              android:background="#44aa00"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
              android:layout_width="240dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="end"
              android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
              android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
              android:dividerHeight="0dp"
              android:background="#007799"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I've asked @roman-nurik about this in his [g+ post](https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/bjiNbjAFsT2) about DrawerLayout presentation and he pointed out that: _"No, definitely not intended to be used with vertical gravities"_ so I guess there's no point on trying to get this to work. Any alternatives to implement vertical drawers?

Comment: mabe you could use SlidingDrawer ?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer which makes it possible to slide from any side by few lines of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no official reference for DrawerLayout to use "Bottom" or "Top" Gravity - [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer%28int%29)

> public void openDrawer (int gravity)
>
> Open the specified drawer by animating it out of view.
>
> Parameters gravity
>
> Gravity.LEFT to move the left drawer or Gravity.RIGHT for the right.
>   GravityCompat.START or GravityCompat.END may also be used.

If you want to use other visual effects - use other library

Answer (score 11):

We have recently implemented this functionality in the Umano App and opened sourced it:

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: It seems this only supports sliding up from the bottom, not sliding down from the top as the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

The [Menu-Drawer](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer) library by Simon Vig Therkildsen works well as a standard sliding menu drawer but also supports top and bottom drawers. His sample application has examples on how to implement the menu with TOP/BOTTOM gravities.